# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setString' was called on null

Tags: flutter

Through the application, I make inquiries from the database to get some previously stored data. I try to store id in myPreferences but I get error like that:

```
E/flutter (29170): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setString' was called on null.
E/flutter (29170): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29170): Tried calling: setString("id", "6")
E/flutter (29170): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (29170): #1      MyPreferences.commit (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/MyPreferences.dart:32:30)
E/flutter (29170): #2      AddCommentsState.getLogin.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:82:23)
E/flutter (29170): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1240:30)
E/flutter (29170): #4      AddCommentsState.getLogin (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:76:5)
E/flutter (29170): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29170): #5      AddCommentsState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:57:9)
E/flutter (29170): #6      interval.function (package:flutter_apptestqeuriy/AddComment.dart:21:9)
E/flutter (29170): #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (29170): #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (29170): #9      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (29170): #10     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (29170): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (29170): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (29170): #13     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
E/flutter (29170): #14     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (29170): #15     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
E/flutter (29170): #16     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
E/flutter (29170): #17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter (29170):
```

I store the number through the following query:

```
  Future<String> getLogin() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://xxxxxxxxx/ApplicationP.php"),);
    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
        data = convertDataToJson['result'];
      if (data != null) {
        user_name = data[0]['id'];
        _myPreferences.id = user_name;
       _myPreferences.commit();

      }
    });
  }
```

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyPreferences {
  static const ID = "id";


  static final MyPreferences instance = MyPreferences._internal();

  static SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  String id = "";


  MyPreferences._internal() {}

  factory MyPreferences() => instance;

  Future<SharedPreferences> get preferences async {
    if (_sharedPreferences != null) {
      return _sharedPreferences;
    } else {
      _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      id = _sharedPreferences.getString(ID);

      return _sharedPreferences;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> commit() async {

    await _sharedPreferences.setString(ID, id);

  }

  Future<MyPreferences> init() async {
    _sharedPreferences = await preferences;
    return this;
  }

  static Future<bool> clearPreference() async {
    if (_sharedPreferences != null) {
      _sharedPreferences.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

I followed up on some similar titles here but the problem is different.

I don't know if anyone knows a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `_sharedPreferences` instance is not initialized.

```
Future<bool> commit() async {
    _sharedPreferences ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await _sharedPreferences.setString(ID, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String TOKEN = "TOKEN";

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

setToken(String token) async {
sharedPreferences  = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sharedPreferences.setString(TOKEN, token);
}

getToken() async {
 return _preferences.getString(TOKEN);
}
```